# What’s the advantage of using LSTM for time series predict as opposed to Regression?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

In neural networks, in general, which model should yield a better and accurate output between both for time series?

Comment: Hi. Can you please check the answer and confirm if this is what you are looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly mentioned, We can use linear regression with time series data as long as:

- The inclusion of lagged terms as regressors does not create a collinearity problem.
- Both the regressors and the explained variable are stationary.
- Your errors are not correlated with each other.
- The other linear regression assumptions apply.

**No autocorrelation is the single most important assumption in linear regression.** If autocorrelation is present the consequences are the following:

- Bias: Your “best fit line” will likely be way off because it will be pulled away from the “true line” by the effect of the lagged errors.
- Inconsistency: Given the above, your sample estimators are unlikely to converge to the population parameters.
- Inefficiency: While it is theoretically possible, your residuals are unlikely to be homoskedastic if they are autocorrelated. Thus, your confidence intervals and your hypothesis tests will be unreliable.

While, The **Long Short Term Memory** neural network is a type of a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). RNNs use previous time events to inform the later ones. For example, to classify what kind of event is happening in a movie, the model needs to use information about previous events. RNNs work well if the problem requires only recent information to perform the present task. If the problem requires long term dependencies, RNN would struggle to model it. The LSTM was designed to learn long term dependencies. It remembers the information for long periods.

To focus on the 1st sequence. The model takes the feature of the time bar at index 0 and it tries to predict the target of the time bar at index 1. Then it takes the feature of the time bar at index 1 and it tries to predict the target of the time bar at index 2, etc. The feature of 2nd sequence is shifted by 1 time bar from the feature of 1st sequence, the feature of 3rd sequence is shifted by 1 time bar from 2nd sequence, etc. With this procedure, we get many shorter sequences that are shifted by a single time bar.

Comment: @Jay - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.